# Integration of amazon SDK in iPhone apps

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can I Implement Small functionality like searching all products on amazon website using AWS SDK(Amazon Web services SDK) in iphone app.....

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the Amazon AWS SDK is about the amazon online store where you can buy goods. It's an API that gives you access to Amazons Server services for cloud computing, databases... and so on. :)

What you you can do though is form a query by simply exchanging the "keyword" in this URL
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1/185-2077263-5307546?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=IPHONE

If you are familiar with HTML you work with the result you get to visualize the products and everything... :)

Hope I could help!

Comment: Hi @JoeKurt Is it possible to add Amazon payment integration in iPhone application?